# conversion from binary to decimal in c language

Tags: c, binary, decimal

i want to convert from binary to decimal but convert function does not return any thing where is the problem ??

```
#include <stdio.h>            
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int convert(int x);   //fun to convert from binary to decimal
int main()
{
    int x;  //binary number
    printf("plz enter binary number !\n\nbinary: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("\ndecimal: ",convert(x));
    return 0;
}

int convert(int x)
{
   int sum=0;   //decimal number
     int i=0;
     int r;  //remainder

   while(x!=0){
   r=x%10;
   sum+=r*pow(2,i);
   x=x/10;
   i++;
      }
   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with debugger?

Comment: input/ output? BTW, do you plan to handle leading 0's?

Comment: printf("\ndecimal: ",convert(x));  you not printing the return value. printf("\ndecimal:%d ",convert(x));

Comment: As others have pointed out - debugging.  DCV.

Comment: Please edit the post and indent your code.

Comment: Read about `printf()`

Comment: Instead of this, read the input as a string and use `strtoul(..., 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
scanf("%i", &x);
printf("%d", x);
```

Comment: Apart from being correct in general, how this helps OP to solve his/her issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should change your `printf` in `main()`.

```
printf("\ndecimal: %d",convert(x));// add %d
```

Because to print a value by `printf` need to spacify the data type such as for `int` `%d` for character `%c`.

Answer (score 0):

binary numbers are series of ones and zeros (0|1), if you are referring to this type of numbers then check this source code below. you may also find this link useful http://www.math.grin.edu/~rebelsky/Courses/152/97F/Readings/student-binary

```
#include <stdio.h>            
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int bintodec(char bin[32]){

    int dec=0;
    while(*bin){

        if((*bin!='0') && *bin!='1')
            break;// only accept '0' & '1'

        dec<<=1;
        dec+=*bin-'0';
        bin++;
    }
    return dec;
}

int main(){

    char bin[32]="";  //i believe binary numbers are series of '1' and '0'

    printf("plz enter binary number !\n\nbinary: ");
    scanf("%s",bin);
    printf("\ndecimal: %d\n",bintodec(bin));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Use format specifier***:
**%d** for integer (in this case)
**%c** for character
**%f** for float value
**%s** for string
**%lf** for double
**%x** for hexadecimal

In this case change print statement to:
printf("\ndecimal: %d",convert(x));

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at the comments and answers on the question, which go back a long while & do really already cover what you have provided. You would be better looking for more up to date questions to work with.